# How to get the values from checkbox as an array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have few checkboxes which generates dynamically via php. I need to pass those checkbox data to another php file for process as an array. I want to pass those data via jquery/ajax. But I cant pass those data as an array. My codes are below,
jquery ajax

```
    var data = {
        url:        '<?php echo get_admin_url()?>admin-ajax.php',
        dataType:   'json',
        action:     'tuh',
        ans_name:   jQuery('[name="ans_name"]').serialize()
    };
  var myRequest = jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function(response){
        //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        jQuery("#widget_poll_id").html(response);
    });
```

Could anyone please tell me , how to solve this problem?

Comment: which data are you talking about?

Comment: `serialize()` doesn't create array it creates string. You are asking for a solution , but you haven't clearly identified a problem

Comment: what is the error of your code? I think It should work. because the data for an AJAX call at last will be turned to string.

Comment: my guess is you want to use `serialzeArray()` instead

Comment: echo "<div class='input'><label><input id='form_ans' class='checkBoxGroup' type='checkbox' name='ans_name' value='$answer_id'/>".$ans_res->answer 

I have this checkbox which is dynamic and quantity of checkbox is dynamic . I need to pass these dynamic data to another php page via ajax. And I tried the jquery codes above. I have to pass these data as an array. But I am unable not pass array .

Comment: first...don't post code in a comment block, where it can't be formatted, and therefore can't be read...delete that and put code and explanation edits in question. `But I am unable not pass array` is not a detailed explanation. What else have you tried?

Comment: And be aware IDs must be unique, just in case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `serializeArray`. See [documentation about this](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
var data = {
    url:        '<?php echo get_admin_url()?>admin-ajax.php',
    dataType:   'json',
    action:     'tuh',
    ans_name:   jQuery('[name="ans_name"]').serializeArray()
};
```